# If $f(x) = x^3+3x+4\;,$ Then value of $ \int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{4}f^{-1}(x)dx$

Tags: calculus

> $[1]$ If $f(x) = x^3+3x+4\;,$ Then value of $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{4}f^{-1}(x)dx$
>
> $[2]$ Evaluation of definite Integral $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}(e-1)\sqrt{\ln\left[1+(e-1)x\right]}dx+\int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2}dx$

$\bf{My\; Try\; for \; (1)::}$ Let  $$\displaystyle I = \int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{4}f^{-1}(x)dx$$

Now Let $f^{-1}(x)=z\;,$ Then $x=f(z)$ and $dx = f'(z)dz$

So Integral Convert into $$\displaystyle I = \int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx+\int_{f^{-1}(0)}^{f^{-1}(4)}z\cdot f'(z)dz$$

Now Using Integration by parts for Second Integral, We get

$$\displaystyle I = \int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx+\left[z\cdot f(z)\right]_{f^{-1}(0)}^{f^{-1}(4)}-\int_{f^{-1}(0)}^{f^{-1}(4)}f(z)dz$$

Now How can I solve after that, and I have seems second Question is same as $1$ one

Help me

Thanks

Comment: Calculate $f^{-1}(4)$ and $f^{-1}(0)$ and then get a value for $I$.

Comment: Thanks  uniquesolution, But I did not Understand How can I calculate it, bcz it is a cubic equation.

Comment: First convince yourself that $f$ is indeed invertible (hint: it is strictly monotone). Next, $f^{-1}(4)$ is easy: $f(x)=4$ if and only if $x^3+3x=0$, so $x=0$. For the other one - well, yes. You do need to find the real root of $x^3+3x+4=0$. Can you maybe guess it? There is only one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $f(x)=x^3+3x+4$, $f'(x)=3(x^2+1)>0$, hence $f$ is an increasing function.

 We have $f(-1)=0$ and $f(0)=4$, hence:
$$ \int_{0}^{4}f^{-1}(x)\,dx + \int_{-1}^{0}f(x)\,dx = (4\cdot 0)-(-1\cdot 0)=0\tag{1}$$
by [a well-known result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions) about the integral of the inverse function. That gives:
$$ \int_{-1}^{1}f(x)\,dx+\int_{0}^{4}f^{-1}(x)\,dx =\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{2}+4=\frac{23}{4}.\tag{2}$$

The second problem can be solved with the same technique, if we notice that the first integral can be written as $\int_{0}^{e-1}\sqrt{\log(1+x)}\,dx$, and the inverse function of the last integrand function is $e^{x^2}-1$.

Comment: Excellent solution.

Comment: As usual, very nice Jack. Also citing the result helped

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather not go by parts (also, it does not work like that anyway). See, an integral is an area below the graph. Draw a graph of $f(x)$. Mark the area which is determined by the first integral. Now, if you turn this picture sideways, the very same curve becomes the graph of $f^{-1}(x)$. Mark the area corresponding to the second integral. See where this gets you.